# Share Video Removal in YT API V2 is a clear Violation of Google Deprication Policy

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages

This is a formal request to KEEP Share Video in V2 of the API until the release of similar functionality in V3.

I run a business that relies on this functionality and my customers rely on being able to share videos directly to their fans through YouTube. And my company and it's employees rely on this revenue for their livelihood.

The deprecation terms clearly state ONE YEAR notice and you are giving us FIVE DAYS??

Screenshot: http://content.screencast.com/users/SharedDocs/folders/Jing/media/be7bd5e9-7785-4198-93e7-7b0b0fac4d6c/2014-03-28_1014.png

PLEASE leave this functionality in until it is included in V3. That is all we are asking.

Thank you YouTube development team.
Sincerely,
Brian Wilson

Comment: I'm in a similar position and seriously how can one of the biggest sites on the internet get rid of an API with a 5 day warning. I'm still shocked...